# Judge OF the [county name] Court of Common Pleas or Judge ON the [county name] Court of Common Pleas?

Tags: word-choice

I see this used both ways in advertising materials, but am not sure which is correct. I could not find any reference to this when searching the internet.

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you have seen each of these used ? What did you search for?

Comment: I have seen both versions used in advertising material. I searched for "Judge of the court or Judge on the court."

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that information.

Answer (score 2):

Both **of** and **on** are used when speaking of such courts.  **of** casts its object as something to which one can *belong* as a member belongs.  **on** casts is object as something which affords a *position*.

> He is a member of the committee.
>
> He has a position on the committee.
>
> He is a member of the court.
>
> He has a seat on the court.
>
> He has been a judge on the Court of Common Pleas for ten years now.
>
> He has been a judge of the Court of Common Pleas for ten years now.

Here are some examples in the wild:

> Lycoming county is within the eighth judicial district; and thus, it appears that the affidavit was sworn before a judge of the court of common pleas of Lycoming county.
>
> And later, after Judge Onion became a Judge on the Court of Criminal Appeals, his twin brother, James, was also elected to serve as judge on the same district district court where their father had served.

Comment: I'd recommend swapping the last two example sentences in the first quote block. The word sequence is currently: *of*, *on*, *of*, *on*, *on*, *of*. Which feels out of place.